# Importing old photos on a Mac, but excluding them from view in an iOS library - possible?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, photos

I've attached an external drive with 1000s of old photos and imported them into the OSX Photos app. The aim is for macOS Photos to analyse them, detect faces then a) include these photos in memories video and b) make them searchable on my iOS devices (this is the key bit).

Basically I'm trying to replicate Google Photos functionality.

I tried an initial import of about 5000 photos into macOS Photos, and it worked fine - faces began scanning. Great.

However.... when I checked my iPhone, my 'Recents' album grew by 5000 photos, some appearing before current snaps, and others appearing after.

This is problematic for me as I use the Recents album to check photos I've taken recently, and don't want to see snaps taken in 2010 in there.

Is there any way to run this import, sync via iCloud Photos and NOT see the imported ones in 'Recent'? I just want them in cloud album / folder for occasional access

Hope this makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "recents" album is not sorted by date the photo was taken. For example, if you receive and import a photo from somebody that was taken 1 year ago, it will appear in the most recent spot in your Recents album despite being an old photo.

If you want to see photos you've recently imported, use the recents album.

**If you want to see photos you've recently taken/created, use the main tab in the Photos app that is sorted chronologically by the photos metadata.**

Comment: Thanks @ezekiel - thats a good shout and make sense.

My only issue now is that when I select photos from within an app like instagram or twitter, those photos are picked from Recents, so you get everything including the old stuff. Can't think of a way around this tbh

Comment: Ah, that's frustrating. Unfortunately that's up to Twitter and Instagram to fix since they chose to always pull the recents album and create their own interface